# Can't reload jQuery Masonry

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I got a site that shows 25 images. I've created a button that says "Load More". The buttons pull 25 images from a php script via Ajax. This part is actually working fine. The problem is, I'm using jquery masonry to align the images.

Right now, it calls the Masonry function when the page is loaded.

```
function Masonry() {
    var $container = $('#fit');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
        });
    });
}
```

However, when I want to call the Masonry() function afterwards, it doesn't work.

If I don't call the Masonry() on load, it works fine in my ajax function.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Calling a bulk masonry() again after the reload fixed this issue for me.

```
$('#fit').append(newitems).masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [appended](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html#appended) to add the new items to the masonry container:

```
$('#fit').masonry( 'appended', newitems);
```

FYI: as an alternative to using a "Load More" button, take a look at using Infinite Scroll: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Comment: Hi Mike, I've actually just tried that
I'm using a function called
var $boxes = $(xmlhttp.responseText);
$('#fit').append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes).masonry( 'reload' ).masonry( 'reloadItems' );

it appends the images, but not as expected I'm afraid. 

Just to give you an idea what ajax returns:
<div class="masonryImage">
  <a data-title="Windows Azure" href="ImageURL.jpg" class="lightbox">
   <img src="ImageURL.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
 </div>

Comment: What do you mean "not as expected"? Looks like it's working now, except that you need to reset the "Load More" button...